# How to convert lines to columns with talend

Tags: talend

I want to convert my input excel's data to columns with talend, like show the picture bellow. Any help please? I'm junior to this 
Regards 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAgoG.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is custom component for this on the Talend Exchange for pivoting rows to columns. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.datalytyx.com/how-to-denormalise-a-dataset-using-talends-tunpivotrow/)